# What files did `make install` copy, and where?

Tags: makefile, installation

Is there a way to get a list of filenames/paths that `make install` copies to the filesystem? Some packages come with a MANIFEST file, but not the ones that I am working with.

Comment: The `porg` package helps you log the list of files with `make install`.  Uninstalling is as simple as reading the list  of files from the porg package log and deleting them.

Comment: You can use the tool `checkinstall` as well to record what `make install` installed and where.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most fool-proof way is to use chroot: have "make install" run inside a chroot jail; compute a list of the files that you had before the installation, and compare that to the list of files after the installation.

Many installations will support either a --prefix configuration option, and/or a DESTDIR environment variable. You can use those for a lighter-wait version of chroot (trusting that the installation will fail if it tries to write to a location outside these if you run installation as a fairly unprivileged user).

Another approach is to replace the install program. Many packages support an INSTALL environment variable that, well, is the install program to use; there are tracing versions of install around.

Answer (score 19):

I was just investigating this myself while compiling a custom version of QEMU.  I used the following method to work out what was installed and where (as well as using it as a basis for a .deb file):

```
mkdir /tmp/installer
./configure --target-list=i386-softmmu
make
sudo make install DESTDIR=/tmp/installer
cd /tmp/installer
tree .
```

*Tree is a utility that recursively displays the contents of a directory in a visually appealing manner - `sudo apt-get install tree` for Debian / Ubuntu users*

Hope that helps someone... it took me a bit of poking around to nut it out, but I found it quite a useful way of visualising what was going on.

Comment: ls -R (along with whatever other formatting options you want) and the -printf option to GNU find are also relevant to answering the "what's in this directory" question.

Answer (score 8):

`make uninstall` might show the files as it removes them if the author of the compiling instructions provides the information to allow an uninstall (it has been awhile since I have done one so I can't say for sure).

Also `make -n install` will do a "dry ru**n**" of the install process and it may be reasonable to extract the information from its results.

Comment: make -n install is unreadable for my part, it lists thousands of lines :(

Answer (score 4):

It differs for every project that you run 'make install' on.  The files which are installed are controlled by the install target in the Makefile being used.  Your best bet is to open the Makefile and search for 'install:' - from there you can see what files will be copied out to your system.

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a snapshot of the contents of the install location before installing
2. Install
3. Compare the current contents with the old contents.

Example:

```
./configure --prefix /usr/local
make -j`nproc`

find /usr/local | sort -u > /tmp/snapshot1
make install
find /usr/local | sort -u > /tmp/snapshot2
comm -3 /tmp/snapshot{1,2} # this prints the files added by `make install` to stdout
```

Answer (score -1):

If the install program you're using doesn't support DESTDIR or --prefix (or an equivalent), I have found that it may be possible to identify new files as follows:

1. Start with as clean a system as possible (a fresh VM image is preferable)
2. Compile the software, wait a few minutes.
3. Install the software package.
4. Find files modified within the past 5 minutes: `sudo find / -mmin -5 -type f` (the find command has a ton of parameters for querying based on file modification / creation times, but this worked pretty well for me; you just need to narrow the time span so that you pick up the files created by the installer but nothing else).

Comment: This is most likely going to result in a lot of false positives due to log files and other activity that may be occurring on the system.