# Qt Installer framework - Copying files to location other than install directory

Tags: linux, qt, build, qt-installer

I know that, whatever data is placed in package/component dir/data, will be copied to the install directory. What I mean is if I have a binary, readme, license.txt inside package/component dir/data/myapp, package/component dir/data/readme, package/component dir/data/license.txt and if I choose my target installation dir to be “/opt/myfirstapp”, then inisde /opt/myfirstapp, I will have 3 files copied, myapp, readme, license.txt.

Having said that, I also have a “/usr” directory with in package/component dir/data/, however this is not the standard “/usr” which will be inside root “/”, it is just a replica. Now inside my replica “/usr” I have some directory hierarchy and some files, like /usr/bin/myapp, /usr/lib/libmyapp.so, /usr/share/icons” and many more, infact a lot. Now I want the replica “/usr” content to be copied to “/usr” (the original usr inside root folder). I should also make sure that I just add new contents to “/usr” (root /usr), but delete any existing content.

Question is clear, some files inside my data directory will have to go to target install dir, but some selected ones (for ex: /usr) will have to be copied to other paths. How do I achieve this.

Comment: Are you using `make install` command to install your app? If so, you need to discover your Makefile and recognize [Variables for Installation directories](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html#index-installation-directories_002c-creating).
Also, this question will help you how to get list of actual files that are used during installation: [What files did `make install` copy, and where?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506462/what-files-did-make-install-copy-and-where)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we have the same problem in my company: we need 2 target directories, one for the exe and one for the libraries (well, it's a bit more complex but in few words...).

After having spoken with Qt support and got the answer that it's actually not possible (*"It is possible only after extracting. After extraction, you can use copy or move operation, unfortunately there is currently no other way."*) I decided to use the AdminTargetDir as the second target directory. This because there's no other way to pass dynamic variables to the IFW. So after installation I call a "finalizeInstall_patch.bat" file passing the TargetDir and AdminTargetDir and this will move the libraries directory from TargetDir to AdminTargetDir. Why a .bat patch file ? because it's actually not possible to move a directory using the methods provided by the IFW. Qt support just opened a suggestion-ticket for our problem: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTIFW-595

I hope that this answer will help others having same similar problems.

NOTE: There is a way to move a directory (on Windows), calling *addOperation("Execute", "cmd /C move source dest...")* but this brings to other problems out of topic here.

Comment: I was doing more or less similar, but wanted to know if there is a better way. Until someone comes with a better answer, this is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for us (Qt Installer, macOS):

```
var args = ["cp", "-R", "@TargetDir@/MyApp.app", "/Applications"];
component.addOperation("Execute", args);
```