# How to uninstall gtsam library

Tags: uninstallation

I have installed gtsam 4 library from : https://bitbucket.org/gtborg/gtsam.git and since I am facing troubles with compilation I want to uninstall it and link to a local version. The problem is that `make uninstall` does not exist. Is there a way to remove it or at least make the local version be used instead of it.
In CmakeLists.txt I have `include_directories` and `link_directories` pointing to the local version but still the gtsam which is installed is the one that is used.

I tried `make -n install` but the make prints about 700 lines which is difficult to follow and reverse what happened.

I found `install_manifest.txt` file in build directory. As I read [here](https://gkiagia.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/introducing-cmake_install/) it contains all the files to be installed. However. I noticed that most of the files are `.h` and some are `.cmake` I do not know if just deleting those files will fix the problem or is going to mess it up.

Comment: General rules for me: try `make uninstall`. If it doesn't work, `make install`, copy-paste paths of installed files and delete them. If `make install` doesn't display which files it installed - see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506462/what-files-did-make-install-copy-and-where.

Comment: I tried `make -n install` but the make prints about 700 lines which is difficult to follow and reverse what happened. And also, would deleting files be enough, I mean environment variables might then be pointing at directories that does not exist for instance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unrelated to programming.

Comment: @AbdallahSobehy consider following chroot recipe. This way you can diff all changes made to a system, including env variables. You can chroot, git init, git add & commit, then make install and see every change made. Also, I doubt this library changed env.

Comment: Thanks for your participation, however the install_manifest.txt file was the key to do it. you can check my answer @strangeqargo

Comment: didn't you forgot to make an edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-ie-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-lin) which is not the top one did the trick, it suggested to remove the files specified in the install_manifest.txt file using the following command :

```
cat install_manifest.txt | xargs echo sudo rm | sh
```

However, it has to be noted that in the comments, it is said it can be dangerous if the install_manifest had important files, so it is essential to have a look what is written there.